# Trying to set up code push, Getting error when trying to save app to appcenter - React Native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

Name contains invalid characters ..

[image]

Comment: is this something new cause i have lots other apps stored with periods in their names

Comment: Looks like you're trying to put a bundle identifier in as the App name field, which seems like it is meant for an app's display name, which should not contain special characters. I assume there are no other special characters covered up by the red?

Comment: I used that format in the past and it worked. I guess they disabled this.. thanks for your response